# Resolving the Issue of libvirtd Dependency While Building libvirt-9.10.0 Source

Tags: linux, libvirt

I encountered an issue while building the libvirt-9.10.0 source code, and the error message is as follows: **ERROR: Problem encountered: libvirtd is required to build QEMU driver.** My system details are as follows:

```
Linux lab.rxzhang.cn 5.10.134-13.an8.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 9 10:39:46 CST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Upon inspecting the meson.build source file, I found the following relevant code snippet:

```
if not conf.has('WITH_LIBVIRTD')
    use_qemu = false
    if get_option('driver_qemu').enabled()
      error('libvirtd is required to build QEMU driver')
    endif
endif
```

According to the code, it seems that the libvirtd daemon is necessary, but for some reason, I am unable to build it successfully. I have already installed the Linux mini system, but the problem persists.

I hope to find some experienced individuals on this forum who can help me resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Does anyone know how to configure the libvirt-9.10.0 source code to build libvirtd correctly?

I appreciate any assistance and advice you can provide. If more information is needed, please feel free to let me know. Thank you!

I'm using the following Meson configuration command:

```
meson setup build -Dsystem=true -Ddriver_qemu=enabled
```

This is logs info：

```
meson.build:1626:6: ERROR: Problem encountered: libvirtd is required to build QEMU driver
```